# AGSQueryTaskDelegate not firing - ARCGis Runtime SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arcgis, esri

I am trying to query all the features from my database through a querytask, but no delegate methods are being invoked.

`@interface MyClass : NSObject <AGSQueryTaskDelegate>`

I created a strong property AGSQueryTask :

`@property(nonatomic, strong)AGSQueryTask* queryTask;`

set the delegate as self:

`self.queryTask.delegate = self;`

but nothing happens.
Ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code of your delegate method and how you call the query task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a silly mistake, because of an uncommented line of code, my querytask got deallocated even before it could call the delegate method.